# Change color line in hline

Tags: sectioning, color, line-breaking

Recently I asked a question about how to draw a line under titles but this line should be flexible is a picture is included or not.

I am trying to change the color of this line but nothing works? does anyone know why?

```
% PACKAGES
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.6cm, right=0.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,25,102}


% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{white}}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}

\begin{document}
\section{Arnaud}
\end{document}
```

How can I set color using RGB stye? Thanks

Comment: Avoid loading the same package multiple times...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the color macro improperly grouped.  That is, you close the group (with a right brace `}`) immediately after changing the color, rather than after painting the `\rule`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.6cm, right=0.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,25,102}


% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}%
  [{\color{green}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}

\begin{document}
\section{Arnaud}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's exactly what I need. I have tried many things but not that. It's now working. Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Issuing `\color{white}` inside a group doesn't really do anything. I'd suggest defining a section rule colour (say) `secrulecolor` which you can adjust to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,25,102}

% Title format
\colorlet{secrulecolor}{black}% Default rule colour
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [\vskip-\topskip{\color{secrulecolor}\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Arnaud}

\colorlet{secrulecolor}{blue}
\section{Arnaud}

\colorlet{secrulecolor}{red}
\section{Arnaud}

\colorlet{secrulecolor}{green}
\section{Arnaud}

\colorlet{secrulecolor}{orange!50}
\section{Arnaud}

\colorlet{secrulecolor}{myblue}
\section{Arnaud}

\end{document}
```